# Change Css of Link Upon Click

Tags: css, hyperlink, click

I want to create some link buttons that change each others css styling upon being clicked. I found some tutorials on how to do this, which halfway works as shown in this fiddle;

http://jsfiddle.net/6m3rb/23/

```
<a id="btn1" class="btn" href="#" onclick="btn2.style.background='#007eff'; this.style.background='#9a3e01';">Button 1</a>
<br /><br />
<a id="btn2" class="btn" href="#" onclick="btn1.style.background='#007eff'; this.style.background='#9a3e01';">Button 2</a>
```

The only problem is that when the link is clicked and the page is loaded, the css-styling of the link resets back to normal, but I want it to keep the styling until the other link is pressed.

As fare as I can imagine, I need to use some javascript to handle this effect, however, javascript isn't the area where I am strongest when it comes to the internet.

Kind regards
Neros

Comment: Your problem is that you are reloading the page, so everything resets because you are changing your active state on the client side and on click. You need to check which page is being loaded and set the active class accordingly (on load). This can be done both on the frontend and backend but without seeing more of your application it is hard to say which approach better.

Comment: Well, the application is just a website where there are two buttons who change styling when "selected". So not sure if the rest of the application is necessary to get this effect.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've solved this problem myself.. I already had the same function on a unordered list, so I simply added the buttons within this list.

Answer (score 0):

What you will want to try is using jQuery, it is a already predifned library of actions. For this situation you will want something in the .css() section here. http://api.jquery.com/css/

Your code would look something like this

```
$('#btn1').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // In this case I am preventing the link from firing you do not need this if you want to trigger the link, also remove e from your function parameters
    $('#btn2').css('background-color': 'red');
});
```

Comment: His problem is not changing the active state on click but detecting the page and moving it accordingly.

Comment: @StefanV. I must not be reading it the same way you are. I'm interested what the correct solution is.

Comment: That is correct. It is not the active state on click. I wish to change the style of the button, and keep that style until something happens, which in this case, is another button is clicked (or the website is left).

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript with JQuery (which is easier to use than pure JavaScript).  Then you can call a function with the `onclick` event.

HTML:

```
<a id="btn1" class="btn" href="#" onclick="changebtn2()">change color of the second button </a>
<a id="btn2" class="btn2" href="#">will change color if you click on the first button </a>
```

and make sure you also declare the JQuery library in the HTML.

JavaScript:

```
function changebtn2(){
   $("#btn2").removeClass("btn2"); //remove the old class
   $("#btn2").addClass("btn2change"); //add the new class with a different color
}
```

CSS:

```
.btn2{
   color: red;
}
.btn2change{
   color: green;
}
```

Comment: That method doesn't seem to work. It doesn't seem to "touch" the button at all. 

I tried creating a empty project to see if anything that I've previously made was affecting it, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

As mentioned, scripting isn't my strong side, but to me, the "function changebtn2()" seems a bit funny. Are you sure its "changebtn2"?

Comment: Mmmmh... you can choose another name instead of changebtn2 but it should work.. Did you think to declare jquery `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>` before adding `<script>function changebtn2() {.....}</script>`?

Comment: I added the code and now something actually happens. However, it continues with the same behavior as from the fiddle. If I add "#" to the href, it works and changes the style. But if I insert a link to a page, it changes the color momentarily upon being clicked, but changes back to the "standard" class when the page is loaded.

Comment: Try to add `return false;` after the `onclick` event : `onclick="changebtn2(); return false;"`

Comment: "Return false" gives the same problem. It prevents the link from sending the user onward to wherever the link is suppose to go :/

Comment: Mmmmh... Try this fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/6m3rb/23/) and tell me if it works. (notice I loaded jQuery and commented a line in the css)

Answer (score -1):

Just replace the href="#" with void

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)">Button 1</a>
```

this void function will stop the browser from passing any query as a request.

Comment: Well, the link is meant to lead to a specific page. With this, it does nothing so won't be of much use.